# nested updatepanels

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

When I put nested updatepanels in outer updatepanel, then in code, it shows that outer panel is around the code of all nested panels while design mode shows outer updatepanel is drawn like one row on top of page and nested updatepanels are drawn below that outside of outer updatepanel. Is this normal behavior or there is some problem in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird... could be an issue with a starting or ending tag, maybe an invalid character or missing >  or / or something...

I wouldn't worry about what it's showing you, as long as the markup is correct, that's what matters the most; I did have some issues with certain controls in the designer.  As long as its correct, everything at runtime will work fine.

HTH.